# php time between 2 dates Y-m

Tags: php, date

I have this code that says if days between 2 dates,
but i need it to work with Y-m instead of Y-m-d
how to achieve this?
example: i need to check if `2016-10` is between `2016-09` and `2016-12`

my code:

```
$paymentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
$contractDateBegin = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dfrom));
$contractDateEnd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dtom));

if (($paymentDate > $contractDateBegin) && ($paymentDate < $contractDateEnd)){

    echo "is between";

}else{

    echo "NO GO!";

}
```

Comment: What needs to be in Y-m format? You're just doing a date comparison.

Comment: 3 dates lets say i need check if 2016-10 is between 2016-09 and 2016-12

Comment: keep wondering why should put -1

Comment: Do you mean between the first day of one month, and the final day of another month?  Can't you just force those values in to your date values?

Comment: Its already fixed thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract Month and Year and compare it.

```
$paymentDateY = date('Y', strtotime($date));
$paymentDateM = date('n', strtotime($date));

$contractDateBeginY = date('Y', strtotime($dfrom));
$contractDateBeginM = date('n', strtotime($dfrom));

$contractDateEndY = date('Y', strtotime($dtom));
$contractDateEndM = date('n', strtotime($dtom));


if ($paymentDateY >= $contractDateBeginY && $paymentDateY <= $contractDateEndY 
&& $paymentDateM >= $contractDateBeginM && $paymentDateM <= $contractDateEndM){
     echo "is between";
}
else
{
     echo "NO GO!";  
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

use `Y-m` is oK: **[Demo](https://eval.in/715739)**

```
$paymentDate=date('Y-m', strtotime($date));;
$contractDateBegin = date('Y-m', strtotime($dfrom));
$contractDateEnd = date('Y-m', strtotime($dtom));

if (($paymentDate > $contractDateBegin) && ($paymentDate < $contractDateEnd)){
    echo "is between";
}else{
    echo "NO GO!";  
}
```

Comment: Wow  you are rights just tested it out with numbers!weird i think it don not work with why my variables .